# vs2010 automation : Get the text value of a EnvDTE.CodeElement

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-generation

So I'm playing around with `EnvDTE`, and the `EnvDTE.CodeModel` API, And I was wondering if there was a way to get the text value represented by a `CodeElement`.

Let's say I have an `CodeAttribute`, is there some way to get a `string` of what the `CodeAttribute` represents, i.e.`[MyAttribute(value="myvalue")]`.

I know it's possible to reconstruct the code using the various properties of the `CodeElement`, at least in some scenarios, but for some things it seems it would be easier to just get the text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CodeElement` interface has the properties `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` which represent the start and end of the element within the buffer.  These contain the Line Number / Column which can be passed to methods like `IVsTextLines.GetLineText` and give you back the value you're looking for.

To get the `IVsTextLines` for a given `CodeElement` you can do the following

```
CodeElement ce = ...;
TextDocument td = ce.StartPoint.Parent;
IVsTextLines lines = td as IVsTextLines;
```

Comment: I guess my next question should be, how do I get a reference to an `IVsTextLines`? I am also wondering if this would require the file to be open in the editor, and thus in the text buffer.  I am trying to implement something project/solution wide, using `Project.CodeModel` so I would be exploring the model without the file being open.  This may not be possible though.

Comment: @MasterMorality did you end up figuring out how to get the reference to IVsTextLines?

Answer (score 3):

```
  void WriteMapping(CodeProperty codeProperty)
 {
   WriteLine("");
   WriteLine("///CodeProperty");
   WriteLine("///<summary>");
   WriteLine("///"+codeProperty.FullName);
   WriteLine("///</summary>");
   if(codeProperty.Getter==null && codeProperty.Setter==null)
       return;
   if(codeProperty.Attributes!=null){
       foreach(CodeAttribute a in codeProperty.Attributes)
        {
            Write("["+a.FullName);
            if(a.Children!=null && a.Children.Count>0)
            {
                var start=a.Children.Cast<CodeElement>().First().GetStartPoint();
                var finish= a.GetEndPoint();
                string allArguments=start.CreateEditPoint().GetText(finish);

                Write("("+allArguments);
            }
    WriteLine("]");
        }
        }
   Write("public "+GetFullName(codeProperty.Type) +" "+codeProperty.Prototype);

    Write(" {");
    //if(codeProperty.Getter!=null && codeProperty.Getter.Access!=vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPrivate)
        Write("get;");
    //if(codeProperty.Setter!=null)
        Write("set;");
    WriteLine("}");

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by @JaredPar, an alternative approach would be:

```
public string GetText(CodeAttribute attribute)
{
    return attribute.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint().GetText(attribute.EndPoint);
}
```

That's it!! (Thanks @JaredPar for the pointers)

**Source:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.editpoint.gettext.aspx